# PHP/SQL - Issue with using two $_GET statements?

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to use two different $_GET statements (within the first two chunks of code) and then pass their values into a SQL statement (in the third chunk of code), however it is incorrectly working out for me. I am wondering if i'm using the the $_GET statement incorrectly?? Thanks for any and all help!

```
if (!(isset($_GET['companyselected']))) {
    $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT DISTINCT Company_ID, CompanyName " . "FROM Company");
    $fields = mysqli_fetch_fields($result);
    echo "<table style='width:900px'><tr>";
    foreach ($fields as $column) 
        echo "<th>" . $column->name . "</th>"; 
    echo "<th>Select Bus Company</th></tr>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($row as $field) echo "<td>" . $field . "</td>";
        echo "<td><a href=\"" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?companyselected=" 
            . $row['Company_ID'] . "\" style=\"color: green;\">Show Routes</a></td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}

if (isset($_GET['companyselected'])) 
    {
        if ($result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT DISTINCT RouteNum, RouteName FROM Route WHERE Company_ID = " . (int)$_GET['companyselected']))
            {
                $fields = mysqli_fetch_fields($result);
                echo "<table style='width:900px'><tr>";
                foreach ($fields as $column) 
                    echo "<th>" . $column->name . "</th>"; 
                echo "<th>Select Bus Company</th></tr>";
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    foreach ($row as $field) echo "<td>" . $field . "</td>";
                    echo "<td><a href=\"" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?routeselected=" 
                        . $row['RouteNum'] . "\" style=\"color: green;\">Display Route</a></td></tr>";
                }
                echo "</table>";
            } 
    }

//error is within the $result variable below

if (isset($_GET['routeselected'])) 
    {
        $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM STOP INNER JOIN RouteStop ON Stop.Stop_ID = RouteStop.Stop_ID WHERE RouteStop.Route_ID = " . (int)$_GET['routeselected'] . " AND RouteStop.Company_ID = " . (int)$_GET['companyselected']);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            echo "{\"title\": '".$row['Stop_ID']."', \"lat\": '".$row['Latitude']."', \"lng\": '".$row['Longitude']."', \"description\": '".$row['StopName']."'},";
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: I have answered below based on what I believe is the issue based on your code but I would also add checking your php error log (if you have one) would help you...it has helped me in my coding time and time again

Comment: There's no problem with using `$_GET` multiple times. What does `var_dump($_GET)` show?

Comment: are you getting an error message? What exactly does "is incorrectly working out for me" mean?

Comment: Hi @webhoodlum....have any of our suggestions or answers helped you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you so much for your responses! Come to find out, I had to concatenate the `(int)$_GET['companyselected']` from the first result of a SQL query into the second result of the SQL query, and it is now working beautifully. Here is the code with the concatenation:

```
echo "<td><a href=\"" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?routeselected=" 
       . $row['RouteNum'] . "&companyselected=" . (int)$_GET['companyselected'] . "\" style=\"color: green;\">Display Route</a></td></tr>";
```

Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT DISTINCT RouteNum, RouteName FROM Route WHERE Company_ID = " . (int)$_GET['companyselected']))
```

to (add single quotes and remove int I would imagine):

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT DISTINCT RouteNum, RouteName FROM Route WHERE Company_ID = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($cxn, $_GET['companyselected']) . "'"))
```

where $cxn can be accessed if you include your 'connect.php' file.

Also try changing this line:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM STOP INNER JOIN RouteStop ON Stop.Stop_ID = RouteStop.Stop_ID WHERE RouteStop.Route_ID = " . (int)$_GET['routeselected'] . " AND RouteStop.Company_ID = " . (int)$_GET['companyselected']);
```

to:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM STOP INNER JOIN RouteStop ON Stop.Stop_ID = RouteStop.Stop_ID WHERE RouteStop.Route_ID = " . mysqli_real_escape_string($cxn, (int)$_GET['routeselected']) . " AND RouteStop.Company_ID = '" .  mysqli_real_escape_string($cxn, $_GET['companyselected']) . "'");
```

If the route numbers are not alphanumeric but only numeric, please remove the single quotes I have placed around the sql $_GETs in my proposed edits.

Comment: Why would quotes be needed around a number?

Comment: Route numbers I believe can have letters in them.....see http://www.rms.nsw.gov.au/roadprojects/projects/alpha_numeric/  I will edit my post.

Comment: But since you cast it to integer with `(int)$_GET['companyselected']`, any letters will be dropped.

Comment: Why would `companyselected` be a route number?

Comment: I agree with @Barmar that casting it as an integer eliminates the need for single quotes. I suspect that companyselected isn't actually a numeric value at the time of PHP's attempted casting.

Comment: Now you need to use `mysqli_real_escape_string` to protect against SQL injection.

Comment: OP stated "however it is incorrectly working out for me. I am wondering if i'm using the the $_GET statement incorrectly??"...OK, I will also add the code to protect against sql injection